# Drawing a circle in Unity and C#

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I have this project that I'm re-doing on Unity after I've implemented it on Android Studio's Java. One component that's part of the UI is a big circle that should be clickable and should display the coordinates of the clicked location on the circle alone.
I'm having a hard time re-implementing this in C# and unity; in Java, this could be simple done by extending the View class and using Path and Canvas to draw the circle. Are there any similar functions in C# and Unity? If not, how can this be done?

Comment: Is your app 2D or 3D?  Are you trying to do this on a Canvas?  Maybe you could render a sprite with your circle and then do a Raycast and calculate the distance from the center of the Sprite?

Comment: it's a 3D app, but this circle is part of 2D interface displayed using a Canvas. Your sprite idea actually is good, I'll look into it but not sure if there's any unknown disadvantages

Comment: So what I've done so far is basically having a sprite, implementing the IPointerDownHandler interface to use the OnPointerDown function, and used RectTransformUtility to get position of touch locally inside my sprite. However, any idea how to do the distance caluclation from center?

Comment: Make the transform the center the center of the sprite.  Then subtract the two vectors and take the magnitude.